# Opening .bat files discordjs

Tags: discord, discord.js

How would I get my discord bot to open a .bat file in a specific directory from 1 command. I'm making a personal bot and I need it for a Minecraft server.

Comment: Hi, thanks for both answers, I encountered some problems first but i made a mistake and used .jar instead of .bat at the end the names, thx for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Child Processes API](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v17.x/docs/api/child_process.html) that's included in Node.js.

Using [`child_process.execFile()`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v17.x/docs/api/child_process.html#child_processexecfilefile-args-options-callback), you can execute a `.bat` or `.cmd` file by passing the relative or absolute file path.

```js
// ES modules
import child_process from 'child_process';
// or CommonJS
const child_process = require('child_process');

child_process.execFile('my_file.bat', () => {
  // continue...
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the child_process library

```
require('child_process').exec('cmd /c filename.bat', () => {
   // your code
});
```